# CSS or HTML help to set maximum width , height of a Image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a block in a table, where profile pictures of the users shows. but to maintain design space, I have made the block size 200px in width and 300px in height. Now I set the below CSS style on the pictures of the users:

```
.max{
max-width:200px;
max-height:300px;
}
```

If there is a large picture (suppose 300x400 px), then it re-sizes to 200x300 px (well doing). But my problem is that if there is a small picture (suppose 100x150px), then also it re-sizes it to 200x300px. But I want to set maximum width and height. So in my situation I want to display the original size of the pictures if it is smaller then 200x300px . But if it is large picture, then it will re-size to 200x300px. any help plz (how I can do it ?)...
--(internet explorer 8.0 tested)

If it cannot do in css, html is there any option to do in JavaScript ?. Is there any good source available ?

Comment: We are probably going to need some more HTML / CSS to help. The problem probably isn't in the definition of the `max` class.

Comment: If you know the images when you build the page, a simple ID tag is the solution, but when user uploads the image, you'll have to use scripting (PHP or Javascript etc), html and CSS solutions may not be available

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.max{
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Specify td width to 200px and for the table - table-layout:fixed.

That should solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Max width and height are just that.. a max, so, it shouldn't be affecting the smaller images.

I just made a text html page and the smaller images worked fine with the max height and width set.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
 .max  {
    max-width: expression(this.width > 200 ? 200: true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

don't know much about css but this should do it in jquery

```
$('.images_class').each(function(){
  height = $(this).height();
  width = $(this).width();
  if( height > 200 || width > 300)
    $(this).css('height','200px').css('width','300px');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

... you might have to resort to javascript, if I understand your question correctly something like this might do it:

```
$(document).ready( function(){

$('img').each( function(){
    if(  ($(this).width() < 200) && ( $(this).height() < 300 ) ){
        $(this).css({'width' : $(this).width() +'px', 'height' : $(this).height() + 'px' )          
    }
})
```

})

... this would involve jQuery, didn't have a chance to test either.

Answer (score -1):

What you are saying is extremely strange.

It sounds like actually you are setting `width` and `height` rather than `max-*`.

I suggest you create a simple [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) and see if the problem remains. If yes, then post a URL and I can look into it.